# What config do I have to change for multiple Tomcat instances to use separate context.xml files?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I've set up two tomcat instances running on different ports on the same Windows machine. One is for Alpha, the other is for Development. I've deployed the Alpha and Dev wars (same app name, different settings in META-INF/context.xml) to each server.

The Tomcat directories have the exact same content except for:

- Wars deployed are different (I started fresh, removed webapps/* war files and dirs)
- conf/server.xml files are different (set different ports)
- bin/catalina.bat files are different (changed CATALINA_HOME to the full path of each instance)

The rest is the same.

The thing is that META-INF/context.xml files of each war point to different databases, one for dev and one for alpha. More specifically the connection URL is different, and even more specifically only the database name is different (the string between the slash and the question mark of the URL).

However, after starting both instances for some reason they BOTH point at the Dev database. That is, they both are presumably reading the Dev context.xml, and probably the same webapps/AppName folder

How is that possible?

When I start the Dev tomcat the console displays the values of CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE, CATALINA_TMPDIR and CLASSPATH, and they all show full paths to the Dev tomcat directory.

When I start the Alpha tomcat the console displays the values of those variables as well, and they all show full paths to the Alpha tomcat directory (so the paths seem to be OK).

I checked the deployed alpha_tomcat_dir/webapps/AppName/META-INF/context.xml file and it DOES show alpha database configuration.

But at runtime it still uses the db information of the Dev database.

Where else should I look?

These are the context.xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/hng" 
        auth="Container"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"

        maxActive="60" 
        minIdle="5"
        maxIdle="60" 
        maxWait="10000"
        testOnBorrow="true" 
        testOnReturn="true"
        testWhileIdle="true" 
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="20000" 
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="180"
        logAbandoned="true"

        username="root"
        password="<removed>" 

        url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true" />

</Context>
```

The files only differ in the database name. It's "hngdev" for dev and "hngalpha" for alpha (instead of dbname)

Comment: what db server is used? mysql?

Comment: want to share your context files with us?

Comment: There's the config.xml files. I'm 100% sure it's just the db difference, I checked the diff in winmerge just in case my eyes are playing tricks with me.

Comment: Wait! When I do a lookup like DataSource ds = (DataSource)(new InitialContext()).lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/hng") ... is that resource that I look up shared across multiple processes? Is there a chance that it does not attempt to build the connection pool from my context.xml cause there's one resource with that path already living in another java process?

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that the context content is right,

Then I would say check your settings in the database server.

could be that you have created the user wrong in the database server? Given same rights for alpha user and dev user. Maybe you did copy-paste same grant user queries for both?

Also you could try to change db information in alpha context, to some wrong user info/port. Does it still connect?

Comment: Yes, I actually shouldn't need to check the db, cause I remote-debugged the app in both tomcat instances and inspected the datasource, and they both showed the same connection url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/hngalpha?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true

Comment: And yes, you're right, I am using the same user for dev and alpha, and it's granted access to both dbs (which is a terrible practice), but the problem is still that for both instances envCtx.lookup("jdbc/hng") returns a DataSource pointing at the dev database (hngdev), even though the context.xml file for alpha specifies hngalpha as the database in the db connection URL.

Comment: I did check what you said, I set a wrong username and password, and an inexistent database name. It still successfully connects to dev. So I'm kinda sure that alpha's context.xml is never read, and maybe the whole webapp content is never used. The weird thing is that when I launch the alpha instance it DOES expand/deploy the war

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a context.xml file equal to the dev environment's in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[webappname].xml

Due to my server.xml configuration the context descriptor was once copied there before I duplicated the whole tomcat directory structure to make the alpha tomcat environment. And due to my server.xml configuration it was not updated on new deploys of the app. The datasource information was being read from $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[webappname].xml, which I didn't know or expect.

Here's the detailed explanation of how contexts and deployments work on different server configurations:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html